# Use JSONPath Filter Expression in AWS Step Function with variable in condition

Tags: jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I would like to filter a specific object from an array using a JSONPath filter expression within an AWS Step Function.

The JSONPath expression: `$.IncidentRecordSummaries[?(@.Title==$.TitleFilter)].Arn`

The data to filter on:

```
{
  "TitleFilter": "ALARM [hello]",
  "IncidentRecordSummaries": [
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/foo/abc",
      "CreationTime": "2023-02-23T16:54:34.241Z",
      "Impact": 3,
      "IncidentRecordSource": {
        "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/cs-mon-incidents-ms-ac-cloudwatch-sfn/step-functions-express-123",
        "InvokedBy": "states.amazonaws.com",
        "Source": "aws.cloudwatch"
      },
      "Status": "OPEN",
      "Title": "ALARM [hello]"
    },
    {
      "Arn": "arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/bar/def",
      "CreationTime": "2023-02-23T16:25:51.772Z",
      "Impact": 3,
      "IncidentRecordSource": {
        "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/cs-mon-incidents-ms-pest-devops-guru-sfn/step-functions-express-456",
        "InvokedBy": "states.amazonaws.com",
        "Source": "aws.cloudwatch"
      },
      "Status": "OPEN",
      "Title": "ALARM [world]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected result:

```
["arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/foo/abc"`]
```

Actual result:
`[]`

Any suggestion how to solve this issue?

The filter is working with a string literal being used in the expression: `$.IncidentRecordSummaries[?(@.Title=='ALARM [hello]')].Arn` returns the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

This form of filter expression should work for `Parameters`, `ResultSelector`, `InputPath`, or `OutputPath`. See an example below using [Pass states](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) and [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-inputpath-params.html#input-output-parameters).

```
{
  "StartAt": "Generate Input",
  "States": {
    "Generate Input": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "TitleFilter": "ALARM [hello]",
        "IncidentRecordSummaries": [
          {
            "Arn": "arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/foo/abc",
            "CreationTime": "2023-02-23T16:54:34.241Z",
            "Impact": 3,
            "IncidentRecordSource": {
              "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/cs-mon-incidents-ms-ac-cloudwatch-sfn/step-functions-express-123",
              "InvokedBy": "states.amazonaws.com",
              "Source": "aws.cloudwatch"
            },
            "Status": "OPEN",
            "Title": "ALARM [hello]"
          },
          {
            "Arn": "arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/bar/def",
            "CreationTime": "2023-02-23T16:25:51.772Z",
            "Impact": 3,
            "IncidentRecordSource": {
              "CreatedBy": "arn:aws:sts::12345:assumed-role/cs-mon-incidents-ms-pest-devops-guru-sfn/step-functions-express-456",
              "InvokedBy": "states.amazonaws.com",
              "Source": "aws.cloudwatch"
            },
            "Status": "OPEN",
            "Title": "ALARM [world]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "Next": "Extract Arns"
    },
    "Extract Arns": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true,
      "Parameters": {
        "key.$": "$.IncidentRecordSummaries[?(@.Title==$.TitleFilter)].Arn"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When you run this, you will get the following output:

```
{
  "key": [
    "arn:aws:ssm-incidents::12345:incident-record/foo/abc"
  ]
}
```

I wonder if you might be using this in a Task state after calling an API using [AWS SDK Service Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/supported-services-awssdk.html). In which case, the response you get back is the full API response where the data you want is under the `Payload` key. In which case you need you need to use
`$.Payload.IncidentRecordSummaries[?(@.Title==$.Payload.TitleFilter)].Arn`
instead of
`$.IncidentRecordSummaries[?(@.Title==$.TitleFilter)].Arn`